# API StackOverFlow, "quota_max"

Tags: python, stackexchange

Olá, eu estou utilizando um coletor para buscar dados de todos os usuários do fórum do stackoverflow pela API. Só que estou sofrendo com a "quota_max" que são apenas 300 buscas diárias. Já tentei com a função Sleep, coloquei o coletor para dormir até 300 segundos por busca, e mesmo assim ele preenche as cotas e para de retornar. Alguém pode sabe uma maneira de buscar na api sem parar (se possível) ou como funciona o reabastecimento das quotas?

Comment: Pode explicar seu problema em termos de código? Não dá pra usar nenhum cache? Está usando o [**`access_token`**](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)? Leu a documentação?

Comment: Você precisa de uma chave da API para poder expandir esse número. [Nessa resposta](http://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code) verá que com uma chave poderá ter até 10,000 requisições enquanto o limite irá continuar 300 se não a possuir. *Claro, até dá para pegar a informações dos usuários sem chave, mas terá de ser 300 por dia.*

Comment: Meu código em python coleta direto do site da api variando apenas o número da página a ser pesquisada. Cada página me retorna 100 usuários, e eu preciso de todos os usuários. Por mais que eu tente registrar para conseguir uma chave, eu não sei como usá-la

Comment: @Pythowner Não é só passar ela na *query string*? Tipo, se você está fazendo `http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=pt.stackoverflow` você vai passar a fazer `http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=pt.stackoverflow&key=sua_chave`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, você resolveu meus problemas, você é Deus. Muitíssimo obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa de uma chave da API para poder expandir esse número. [Nessa resposta](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code) verá que com uma chave poderá ter até 10,000 requisições enquanto o limite irá continuar 300 se não a possuir. Claro, até dá para pegar a informações dos usuários sem chave, mas terá de ser 300 por dia.

Para usá-la, é só passar ela na query string. Tipo, se você está fazendo:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?
page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=p‌​t.stackoverflow
```

você vai passar a fazer:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?
page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=p‌​t.stackoverflow
&key=sua_chave
```

(quebras de linha adicionadas por legibilidade; obviamente, não há quebras de linha em URLs)

Comment: só para efeito de curiosidade: por que fez essa resposta uma wiki da comunidade? *(comentário efêmero).*

Comment: @DeMarco Bom, o problema foi resolvido nos comentários, por 3 usuários diferentes, mas ninguém postou uma resposta. Sumarizei tudo então, e postei aqui (pra ter uma chance dela ser aceita), mas não faz sentido eu ficar com todo o crédito, por isso o wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer todos os usuários, talvez seja melhor [baixar o data dump do site via bittorrent](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent). Lá, a lista completa de usuários estará disponível como um arquivo XML.